Binomial distribution and bernoulli
I want to prove, not by induction, that if a random variable $X$ has a binomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $p$ then there exists $n$ mutually independent random variables $\left(X_i\right)_{1\le i\le n}$ having the same Bernoulli distribution with parameter $p$ such that $X\sim\sum\limits_{i=1}^nX_i$.
I know I have to use a special case of the Kolmogorov extension theorem :
If $\mu$ is probability measure on $\mathbb R$ then there exists a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ and a real random variable $X$ such that $\mu$ is the distribution of $X$.
And also another fact :
Let $X$ and $Y$ be real random variables. There exists two independent real random variables $X’$ and $Y’$ such that $X\sim X’$ and $Y\sim Y’$.
But I don’t know how do I have to use these, help me please !

I don't think $X=\sum\limits_{i=1}^nX_i$ is possible. But $X$ having same distribution as $\sum\limits_{i=1}^nX_i$ is possible.

Yes you’re right, I corrected

What is it that you are struggling to prove?
(1) that if a probability space has a random variable $X\sim$Bin($n,p$), then it also has $n$ independent random variables each with Ber($p$) distribution. This is false. For example, take $n=2$. You can have a probability space with three elements, with the probabilities of the singleton sets being $(1-p)^2, 2p(1-p), p^2$. This space has a Bin($2,p$) random variable (the elements of the space correspond to the events that this random variable takes values $0$, $1$, $2$), but does not have two independent Ber($p$) random variables.
(2) that for any $n,p$, there exists a probability space with $n$ independent Ber($p$) random variables. There are many standard constructions.
(3) that if you have $n$ independent Ber($p$) random variables,$X_1, X_2, \dots, X$, then their sum $X$ has Bin($n,p$) distribution.
For this, note that the event $\{X=k\}$ can be written as the union
$$
\bigcup_{A\subseteq[n]:|A|=k}
\{X_i=1 \text{ for } i \in A, X_j=1 \text{ for } j\notin A\}.
$$
This union is disjoint and consists of $\binom{n}{k}$ events each of probability $p^k(1-p)^k$. So its probability is $\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^k$ as required.
(4) Something else. Maybe you can clarify.... If your problem turns out to be something else entirely, I can delete this answer.

Yes, actually I should have written “There exists a probability space $(\Omega’,\mathcal F’,\mathbb P’)$ and independent real random variables $X_1,\dots,X_n$ on $(\Omega’,\mathcal F’)$ etc”. My bad

@Richard "Yes" to what, and what does the "etc" mean? I still can't work out what it is that you want to prove and don't know how to. Is it one of (1), (2), (3), above? Is it something else?
